# Simple example of an adapted process that is a martingale for one filtration but not for another

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, filtrations

I have seen [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316498/example-of-adapted-process-that-is-a-martingale-w-r-t-to-one-filtration-but-not). I haven't had Brownian motion yet, is there a simple, more basic example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a problem which has a simple solution that answers your question:

> Suppose $(M_n)$ is a martingale with respect to a filtration $(\mathcal{F}_n)$.  Then $\mathcal{F}_n \subset \mathcal{F}_{n+1}$, so $M_n$ is definitely $\mathcal{F}_{n+1}$-measurable.
>
> Define $\mathcal{G}_n = \mathcal{F}_{n+1}$.  When is $(M_n)$ a martingale with respect to the filtration $(\mathcal{G}_n)$?

Here's the solution in case you need it:

> If $(M_n)$ is a martingale with respect to $(\mathcal{G}_n)$, then
>  $$M_n = \mathbb{E}[M_{n+1}\mid \mathcal{G}_n] = \mathbb{E}[M_{n+1}\mid \mathcal{F}_{n+1}] = M_{n+1}$$

This resolves your question because

> there exist non-constant martingales indexed by $\mathbb{N}$.  E.g. A simple random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Hello ! When seeing your question I was thinking that the answer should be that it is a martingale with respect to $\mathcal{G}_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ but indeed it implies that $(M_n)$ is constant with respect to the time index. However I did not understand the second part about the simple random walk, it is in link with the question you asked in your answer ? Thank you !

Comment: @coboy I'm not sure where your confusion lies.  If $M_n$ is a simple random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$, then $M_n \neq M_{n+1}$, so while it is a martingale with respect to its natural filtration $(\mathcal{F}_n)$, it's not a martingale with respect to $(\mathcal{F}_{n+1})$.